# Fetching data from a table and storing in variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have website settings stored in a table like this:

```
+---------+-------------+
| id      | value       |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 | title       |
|       2 | description |
|       3 | email       |
|       4 | keywords    |
+---------+-------------+
```

How can I select them and assign them to variables ($title, $desc, $email, $key)

```
// Get Website Infos
$result=$db->query("SELECT `value` FROM `settings`");
if($result->num_rows >= 1){
    $row=$result->fetch_assoc();

    $otitle=$row['value'];
    $odescription=$row['value'];
    $oemail=$row['value'];
    $okeywords=$row['value'];
}
```

but it only get the first row 'title',any idea how to do it or better way to save settings.

**UPDATE:**

If you are reading this question now, don't use this structure to store your settings, use the one suggested by Yellow Bird in the answers.

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Please avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: Is the ID auto generated? If yes, you should add a `key` column to identify the `value`. Results from MySQL are not ordered by default, when you get a value, how you know what it stands for?

Comment: @DanFromGermany I Know That Id 1 Is For Title And Id 2 For description....
The Second Thing Why Someone Downvoted me ? :/

Comment: @MehdiBounya IDs might change or simply be not identifyable by someone else + the order of the result is not guaranteed to be 1,2,3,4,5. MySQL can also return 3,2,5,1,4.

Comment: mm Thank You @DanFromGermany I Didn't Know That I Thinked That Every Time I Do A Query Select They Will BE In The Same Order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to loop with your `fetch_assoc()` method :

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT `value` FROM `settings`");

if ($result->num_rows >= 1){

    $data = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['value'];
    }
}

var_dump($data);
```

As DanFromGermany noticed in comments, your db structure is probably not done the right way. You should have a design like this :

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+
| id      | key         | value        |
+---------+-------------+--------------+
|       1 | title       | title value  |
|       2 | description | desc value   |
|       3 | email       | email value  |
|       4 | keywords    | keyw value   |
+---------+-------------+--------------|
```

And then, your code would look like this :

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT key, value FROM `settings`");

if ($result->num_rows >= 1) {
    $data = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[$row['key']] = $row['value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole concept is fail, how you know which of the data is what kind of setting without a key?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Well, I didn't say his db structure is correct. I just show him why he is getting only one value. I edited to show him a different way of building his table.